# Unexpected behaviour of AppDomain.MonitoringSurvivedMemorySize

Tags: .net, monitoring, appdomain

I am trying make use of the [MonitoringSurvivedMemorySize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.monitoringsurvivedmemorysize%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) property of .Net AppDomain Class.

Only Problem being I can't see how the values my Application receives from this Property fit the description of the Property given on msdn.

The discrepancy I observe consists of the Property returning a value that I know is too low because the returned value differs from the value returned by a previous call and in between those two calls the amount of memory referenced by the AppDomain was never as low as the new returned value.

I've searched SO, google and connect.microsoft.com for "AppDomain Monitoring" but could not find anything that seemed to be related to this particular problem described above.

To make sure this hasn't to do anything with other parts of my application I created a new ConsoleApplication with the following code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WindowWidth = 133;

        AppDomain.MonitoringIsEnabled = true;

        var Queue = new Queue<byte[]>();

        var BlockSize = (int)1e+6; 

        var ToggleAllocation = true;

        while (true)
        {
            if (Console.KeyAvailable)
            {
                var Input = Console.ReadKey(true);

                if (Input.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
                {
                    break;
                }

                if (Input.Key == ConsoleKey.C)
                {
                    GC.Collect();
                    Console.WriteLine("Collect");
                }

                ToggleAllocation = !ToggleAllocation;
            }

            Thread.Sleep(100);

            if (!ToggleAllocation)
            {
                continue;
            }

            Queue.Enqueue(new byte[BlockSize]);

            while (100 < Queue.Count)
            {
                Queue.Dequeue();
            }

            var ExpectedLowerBound = Queue.Count * BlockSize;

            var MonitoringSurvivedMemorySize = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.MonitoringSurvivedMemorySize;
            var MonitoringTotalAllocatedMemorySize = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.MonitoringTotalAllocatedMemorySize;

            Console.WriteLine(
                "Queue.Count=" + Queue.Count.ToString() +
                ", SurvivedMemorySize=" + MonitoringSurvivedMemorySize.ToString() +
                ", TotalAllocatedMemorySize=" + MonitoringTotalAllocatedMemorySize.ToString() +
                ", ExpectedLowerBound=" + ExpectedLowerBound.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

this function simply allocates some memory from time to time to make sure a gc will eventually happen and prints out the values received by MonitoringSurvivedMemorySize.

To make sure the problem isn't due to some debugger "features", I switched the Project to the default release configuration and ran the programm from the explorer.

When I run this program, [MonitoringSurvivedMemorySize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.monitoringsurvivedmemorysize%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) returns 0 for some iterations, then after some iterations (I assume after the first gc) a higher value that meets my expectations. But after some more iterations the returned value jumps back to zero. It also returns values different from zero but far to low sometimes.

I set Target framework to ".NET Framework 4 Client Profile"

What am I doing wrong?

Can you repro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into the same Issue using .NET Framework 4.5 and filed it at microsoft as a bug.
Now they provided an answer and fixed it (for .NET Framework 4.5)

Link to the ticket at microsoft: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/765296/appdomain-monitoringsurvivedmemorysize-property-returns-wrong-value-after-gen-0-collection

The quote below originates from the page linked above:

> This was a documentation bug, rather than a GC bug. The documentation
>   at
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.appdomain.monitoringsurvivedmemorysize(v=vs.110).aspx
>   was modified to read:
>
> "The statistics are updated with each garbage collection. However,
>   they are guaranteed to be accurate only after a full, blocking
>   collection; that is, a collection that includes all generations and
>   that stops the application while collection occurs. For example, the
>   GC.Collect() method overload performs a full, blocking collection.
>   (Concurrent collection occurs in the background and does not block the
>   application.)"
>
> --Ron Petrusha Common Language Runtime User Education Microsoft Corporation

due to the long response time observed I'll refrain from asking for clarification on .NET 4.0 at microsoft and instead hereby high-handedly declare this as an valid answer to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation (from the link you provided), you should expect updated statistics only after a full blocking collection. Try adding a call to [GC.Collect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe0c2357%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in your test rig.

Comment: I already accounted for this dependency you mentioned. The Problem isn't that it's updating at the wrong time but it's updating to a wrong value. I added a call to GC.Collect to the code (and updated the first post accordingly) and here is what happens: When I call GC.Collect the Property returns a reasonable value for some calls after the forced Collect but later again returns zero. Maybe the forced Collection could be used for some kind of workaround.

Comment: Most probably we are missing something. Try to register for notifications before GC blocking collcetions. Have a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc713687.aspx